# Mysql view cannot have subquery in from statement

Tags: mysql, gps

I know this has been asked before but I cannot figure out how to rearrange my query.

Basically I have one database that is being updated every second with the current GPS location in DD. I have another database with some locations in DMS format. What I need to do is create a view that joins the current location with the other database so users can query the one table and get results that are relevant for that location. I cannot feed the location into the database query, I have to use the GPS location.

I have the qorking query below.

```js
select * from(select("") as nav_non, latitude as current_lat, longitude as current_lon from navtime.gps_data order by id desc limit 1) nav left join(select * , ("") as sel_non,
  if (substring(loc, 7, 1) = 'N', round(((substring(loc, 1, 2) * 3600000) + (substring(loc, 3, 2) * 3600000 / 60) + (substring(loc, 5, 2) * 3600000 / 60 / 60)) / 1e7, 6), round(((substring(loc, 1, 2) * 3600000) + (substring(loc, 3, 2) * 3600000 / 60) + (substring(loc, 5, 2) * 3600000 / 60 / 60)) / 1e7, 6) * -1) as `latitude`,

    if (substring(loc, 16, 1) = 'E', round(((substring(loc, 8, 4) * 3600000) + (substring(loc, 12, 2) * 3600000 / 60) + (substring(loc, 14, 2) * 3600000 / 60 / 60)) / 1e7, 6), round(((substring(loc, 8, 4) * 3600000) + (substring(loc, 12, 2) * 3600000 / 60) + (substring(loc, 14, 2) * 3600000 / 60 / 60)) / 1e7, 6) * -1) as `longitude`
  from ssd.sel where length(loc) = '16') sel on nav.nav_non = sel.sel_non where `longitude`
between `current_lon` - 200 / abs(cos(radians(`current_lon`)) * 69) and `current_lon` + 200 / abs(cos(radians(`current_lon`)) * 69) and `latitude`
between `current_lat` - (200 / 69) and `current_lat` + (200 / 69)
```

Here is the databases

```js
--
-- Database: `navtime`
--
CREATE DATABASE `navtime` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_swedish_ci;
USE `navtime`;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `gps_data` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `latitude` double(11,6) NOT NULL,
  `longitude` double(11,6) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO `gps_data` (`id`, `latitude`, `longitude`) VALUES
(2016, 10.534520, -43.345310);
--
-- Database: `ssd`
--
CREATE DATABASE `ssd` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_swedish_ci;
USE `ssd`;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `sel` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `loc` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `data1` text NOT NULL,
  `data2` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;


INSERT INTO `sel` (`id`, `loc`, `data1`, `data2`) VALUES
(10, '351224N 1231212W', 'test data1', 1),
(11, '351224N 0931212W', 'test data1', 1),
(12, '351224N 0931122E', 'test data1', 2),
(13, '351214N 0951122E', 'test data3', 3),
(13, '351214N 1451122E', 'test data3', 3);
```

Comment: This is nothing new (for MySQL).  If you cannot rewrite the query, then use a separate view for the subquery in the `from`.

Comment: Thanks that helped.

Created 3 views and it worked. easy solution right in front of my face.